# Inserting a link inside a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i change the page when someone clicks an option inside the select tag ?

```
<select>
  <option><a href="/1" >1</a></option>
  <option><a href="/2" >2</a></option>
  <option><a href="/3" >3</a></option>
</select>
```

Comment: By moving the logic to the options onClick() event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ONCHANGE` event of java-script as follow

```
<select name="forma" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="Home.php">Home</option>
    <option value="Contact.php">Contact</option>
</select>
```

In your case

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value=="/1" >1</a></option>
  <option value=="/2" >2</a></option>
  <option value="/3" >3</a></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Be careful when doing this though, as some browsers fire `change` events when navigating `select` elements via the keyboard. So people using the keyboard will only be able to select the first item in these browsers (some IEs)

Comment: Yes I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onchange` event:

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
```